# VirtualHost/htacess : how to point a subdomain to an url parameter?

Tags: .htaccess, virtualhost, rewrite, apache-2.4, wildcard-subdomain

I must create a multi-language website. 
In order to achieve this aim, I want to point subdomain representing a language to the 1rst URL parameter (GET variable) of the domain in my `virtualhost` or `htaccess` configuration.

The scheme is the follow :

```
example.com => / 

([a-z-]+).example.com => /?lang=$1

([a-z-]+).example.com/directory1/ => /directory1/?lang=$1

([a-z-]+).example.com/directory1/page.html => /directory1/page.html?lang=$1
```

etc... whatever the number of directories and pages.

So, according to this scheme :

```
en-en.example.com matches /?lang=en-en

en-en.example.com/directory1/ matches /directory1/?lang=en-en

en-en.example.com/directory1/page.html matches /directory1/page.html?lang=en-en
```

etc... whatever the number of directories and pages.

So how can I do that in my apache configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this in your .htaccess or virtual host config file will do the trick; This matches only two-letter subdomain names - adjust the first regex accordingly... e.g. ([a-z-]+)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} "^([a-z]{2})\.example\.com$"
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" http://example.com$1?lang=%1
```

Comment: Hello, It works, but I forgot to say that the url with get parameter (lang?=en) must be transparent. That is say :
If you type in the browser url bar en.example.com, the url remains en.example.com but in the background the right url is example.com/?lang=en. Because in your solution, en.example.com redirects to example.com?lang=en, so it's not transparent.

It is possible to do that ?